# 最后吃的菜 or 吃最后的菜？

Tags: translation, grammar

I had a friend who said there is a slight difference in the two phrases.  But I don't see any difference between the two expressions.  Could anyone explain it?

Thanks,
Rachel

Comment: 最后吃的菜 = the dish eaten last/the last dish to be eaten or 吃最后的菜 = eat the last dish. First phrase places emphasis on last + eating, second on the last dish.

Comment: 吃**到**最後的菜, if treated as a noun (i.e. 那一道吃到最後的菜), would be identical to 最後吃的菜.

Comment: confirming preceding comment, just as in English, adjective 后 with degree adverb 最 in 1st case functions as adverbial (状语），in 2nd as attributive (定语）。

Answer (score 5):

> 最后吃的菜 = 最后吃的(that you eat last) + 菜(dish/food);
>
> so, 最后吃的菜 = "the dish that you eat last"

"最后吃的菜" is a noun phrase and it is "菜" essentially.

> 吃最后的菜 = 吃(eat) + 最后的菜(the last dish / the leftovers)；
>
> so, 吃最后的菜 = “eat the last dish / leftovers”

"吃最后的菜" can be regared as an imperative sentence and it means "eat something". If you put a subject at the beginning of it（"我吃了最后的菜"/“我要吃最后的菜”，etc.）, it would be easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you went to a nice restaurant for a nice meal.

Case 1: you had the meal, course by course. In this case 最后吃的菜=(吃)最后的菜=dessert

Case 2：you left in the meal for some reason. In this case 最后吃的菜=the dish you didn't finished. (吃)最后的菜=dessert.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put these statements in their context to be certain of their exact meaning. Without further context, I would say:

最后吃的菜 = the (very) last dish(es) I ate (of a meal)

吃最后的菜 = the last dish(es) (of a meal which) I am eating/I haven't eaten yet

Answer (score 0):

The last dish you eat (最后吃的菜) may not be the dish that is served last (最后的菜).